# "Transfeminine" vs. "trans feminine" (gender identity term)

Tags: word-choice, american-english, terminology, offensive-language, political-correctness

I am writing an article and need to select between "transfeminine" and "trans feminine", in reference to a gender identity descriptor. Both terminology choices are seen in scholarly literature, but "transfeminine" appears to be more common. I am familiar with the fact that "trans women" is considered an accepted term, whereas "transwomen" is not, because "trans women" treats "trans" as an adjective/modifier of "women," indicating that trans women are within the category of women, vs. a distinct category requiring a separate and unique term.

However, I have not seen this articulated for / generalized to "trans feminine" vs. "transfeminine" and I could imagine culturally current and informed justifications for using either term. I could also foresee near-future culture and language evolving to favor one term, or not, and while I know that such changes can't be *known* in advance, they may be predictable. So, if you have any thoughts / input on the pros and cons of using either term in a publication, I appreciate it.

Comment: This is a good question, but probably not a good fit for this site.  EL&U, like most Stack Exchange sites, likes questions with a single right answer.  As you've noted, there are probably good arguments for using either form.  You could probably make this question conform better to EL&U expectations by changing it from "which is better" to "what are the pros and cons of either choice".

Comment: I agree SE isn't the best place (for various reasons). The best I can suggest is to check out sites that are sympathetic to trans issues.  [Stonewall](https://www.stonewall.org.uk/help-advice/faqs-and-glossary/list-lgbtq-terms) uses "trans feminine" in their glossary but not consistently elsewhere. [Nonbinary Wiki](https://nonbinary.wiki/wiki/Transfeminine) uses different versions but says transfeminine is oldest. [RationalWiki](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Transgender_glossary#Transfeminine.2FTransfemme) uses "transfeminine" without any explanation. So it's not very clear which is preferred.

Comment: In fact, Nonbinary Wiki has '[t]ransfeminine (also written trans-feminine or trans feminine, and sometimes abbreviated to transfem or transfemme)'. New compounds often have two (or three) of the possible formats, open / hyphenated / closed forms, in use. Where there are no reasons not to, the open and then the hyphenated forms are often discontinued, usually faster in the States than in the UK. //// But editors / institutions often make pronouncements on their preferred style choice.